# Azure local debugging

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am working on a Azure web app. The problem is that I need to publish the entire app on the live server every single time I change something. What happens if I click Debug, is that it sends me to localhost:XXXXX, but immediately redirects me to Azure login page and after I login I get sent to the Azure live web site.

I don't care if I have to disable login,debugging locally without login will do for now.

EDIT: I just fixed this by replacing

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

with

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

It will do the trick for now, but I'd like to know if there are more elegant solutions using Azure Storage Emulator

Comment: Are you using Azure AD for you Web App?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Azure AD

Comment: You can change your redirect URI when testing.

Comment: A general solution for this kind of problem would be using app settings. You can store your redirect URI in app settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use App Settings to store something like that. For Example, here is something in your Web.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="<client id of your AD application>" />
    <add key="ida:AppKey" value="<key of your AD application>" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.windows.net/{0}" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="graphDir1.onMicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="<tenant id of your AD>" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:44322/" />
    <add key="ida:GraphApiVersion" value="2013-11-08" />
    <add key="ida:GraphUrl" value="https://graph.windows.net" />
    <!--
      To authenticate using an x509 Client Certificate, populate the CertName value with the subject name of the certificate, e.g. "CN=CertName".
      Leave CertName value empty if you want to authenticate using AppKey instead.
      -->
    <add key="ida:CertName" value="" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Note: Here the `RedirectUri` is the redirect uri after you login. For local testing, it should be a link to the localhost.

Similarly, in Azure, log in to the new portal. Choose your web app and click **Settings** --> **Application Settings** --> scroll down to **App settings**, and enter the corresponding value for your server side.

[image]